# Python threading: Queue workers - hang the program

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm trying to implement a simple Queue with workers that do something.
The program should wait until the workers have finished emptying the queue, and continue execution.
I took the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.join) example and tried to implement it in a class, since this is how it's gonna be implemented in my project.
Like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, n, q):
        self.q = Queue()

        print "Starting workers..."
        for i in range(n):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        print "Workers started"

        for i in range(q):
            self.q.put(i)
        self.q.join()
        print "Exiting"

    def worker(self):
        name = threading.currentThread().getName()
        print "Thread %s started" % name
        while True:
            item = self.q.get()
            print "Processing item %d" % item
            sleep(1)
            self.q.task_done()
```

When instantiating the class `t = Test(2, 100)`, all I can see is the `"Thread... started"` messages and the program hangs.
What is wrong with the code?

EDIT:
I just noticed that while this code hangs in `IDLE` (where I tested it), it performs flawlessly on the command line.
Looks like an environmental problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this have to be an environmental problem. I even tested it on a few different editors and PCs.

Output

```
Starting workers...
Thread Thread-1 started
Thread Thread-2 started
 Workers started
Processing item 0
 Processing item 1
Processing item 2
 Processing item 3
Processing item 4
 Processing item 5
Processing item 6
 Processing item 7
Processing item 8
 Processing item 9
Exiting
```

#### Code:

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading
from time import sleep

class Test:
    def __init__(self, n, q):
        self.q = Queue()

        print "Starting workers..."
        for i in range(n):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        print "Workers started"

        for i in range(q):
            self.q.put(i)
        self.q.join()
        print "Exiting"

    def worker(self):
        name = threading.currentThread().getName()
        print "Thread %s started" % name
        while True:
            item = self.q.get()
            print "Processing item %d" % item
            sleep(1)
            self.q.task_done()

t = Test(2, 10)
```